# Nginx: dynamic proxy from url to subdomain

Tags: redirect, nginx, proxy, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a nginx conf to dynamically redirect a url to a webapp, based on the uri. I use proxypass directive.
For example, I want redirect http://www.example.com/clientname/ to http://clientname.internaldomain.local/webapp

So far, I only succeded replacing new host, but the uri is broken because I can't split it. (Now I can't even replace the host, dunno why ...)

Here is my actual non working conf:

```
    server {
       resolver 192.168.137.71;
       listen   80;
       server_name     tomservpa1;

    location  ~ (^\/(.*)\/) {

                set $ccehost $2;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass              http://$ccehost.internaldomain.local:9780/webapp/$new_request_uri;
                proxy_redirect          off;
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        }

}
```

Did someone already do something like that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the way to do it: (set in production)

```
    location ~* ^/(?<ccehost>.*)/(.*) {
           proxy_intercept_errors on;
           proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
           proxy_pass http://$ccehost.app.ptf:8080/app/$2;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use named captures in the `location` directive is avoid scope and ambiguity issues. For example:

```
location ~ ^/(?<ccehost>[^/]+)/(?<new_request_uri>.*)$ {
    rewrite ^ /webapp/$new_request_uri break;
    ...
    proxy_pass http://$ccehost.internaldomain.local:9780;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It should work, but it doesn't proxify I dont know why.
It tries to get http://nginxhost/ccename
It happened to me before and I didn't know how I fixed this.